# How to sign in to Google account and avoid that Chrome crashes

Tags: google-account, google-chrome

Chrome crashed during regular use on a Mac. After forced quit of Chrome I was unable to sign in to Google repeatedly. I could only find advice to rename the data folder on Windows machine. Any tips for Macs?